# Unable to SSH to my virtual machine via Windows Power Shell ISE

Tags: ssh, powershell, vmware-workstation, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I have a Linux VM guest running in my vmWare host that I want to access using Windows PowerShell ISE. I normally can SSH to my VM, but I cannot with Windows PowerShell ISE.

When I try to do SSH to my virtual machine, the SSH Operation is gets stucked and will not show me any further console or message. I am using an SSH Client that comes with GIT, Windows 8.1 and vmWare Workstation 10.

```
PS C:\> ssh esis@192.168.255.142
ssh : Warning: Permanently added '192.168.255.142' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
At line:1 char:1
+ ssh esis@192.168.255.142
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Warning: Perman...of known hosts.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: This seems to be working just fine for me using Windows 8.1 and the SSH client that comes with git. Have you tried connecting to another host?

Comment: @SgtOJ Your edit has changed the entire context of my question. There is a thing called **PowerShell ISE** in windows. I am able to SSH from PowerShell but not from **PowerShell ISE**

Comment: Have you checked out this [post](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/136939/warning-permanently-added-the-rsa-host-key-for-ip-address-207-223-240-182-to-the-list-of-known-hosts)?

Answer (score 4):

It's limitation of PowerShell ISE.
Any application that will try to control the console pane will fail and/or get stuck.

Some of those commands are already "blacklisted", you can see those in `$psUnsupportedConsoleApplications`.

Error you see is probably not relevant at all: ssh writes information to stderr, and PowerShell generates error on top of this message.

But it's the fact that ssh needs full control over console you are running it in (e.g. to enable you to run things like vim) that's "freezes" ISE. To see the same issue with built in applications you can try the same with netsh:

```
$psUnsupportedConsoleApplications.Remove('netsh')
netsh
```

This should lock ISE as well, for the same reasons ssh is locking it.

BTW: if you want just run a few commands, [plink.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) can be better tool than "normal" ssh. It works just fine in ISE, because it's not trying to take over console.